# How to use v:count in Vim to switch line with line n lines away?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, move

I would like to create a mapping in vim that would switch the current line with a line that is `n` lines away.

So far, I have something like this:

```
:nnoremap gl:<C-U> dd{v:count1}jO<Esc>pjdd{v:count1}o<Esc>p
```

But it does not work. How can I use the v:count variable in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mappings are evaluated exactly as typed. Things like `v:count` are special Vimscript variables, so its value somehow needs to be interpolated into the keys of the right-hand side. With mappings, there are two possibilities:

#### execute

With `:execute`, you can break out from the normal mode (started by `:nnoremap`) into Ex mode and assemble the command; you need `:normal!` to run the normal mode command(s) that were previously just put as the right-hand side. As Vim automatically translates any `[count]` given to the mapping into an Ex range, `<C-u>` is necessary to clear that.

```
nnoremap <silent> gl :<C-u>execute 'normal! yyma' . v:count1 . "jVp'aVp"<CR>
```

#### map-expr

The `<expr>` modifier adds a layer of indirection to mappings: the right-hand side is evaluated and only the result is taken as the commands to run. There's a similar complication with `[count]` here; a preceding `<Esc>` command cancels it (so you only yank a single line).

```
nnoremap <expr> gl '<Esc>yyma' . v:count1 . "jVp'aVp"
```

### your implementation

I assume you chose `gl` as the left-hand side, and the `:<C-U>` is an attempt at escaping, like I've done with my first approach. The space that separates left-hand side from right-hand side is missing there, and the `:normal`, too.

I've made the following changes to the implementation:

- Deleting and pasting next to it complicates the counting; instead, I've used paste over a visual selection (`Vp`); this automatically puts the removed text into the unnamed register (so it can be reused for the second part of the swap).
- Instead of using the count a second time to jump back, I've set a mark (`ma`) for simplicity. You might also be able to employ the *jump list* (`<C-o>`) for this.

#### other implementations

For simple swaps, your implementation might suffice, but it's far from perfect. There might be a desire to swap multiple (e.g. visually selected) lines, redo a swap elsewhere with `.`, and check that the destination line actually exists.

The [unimpaired.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) plugin has a swap mapping `[e`. My [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) also has a robust and universal implementation (as well as many other related ones).